# best solution for analyzing, merging, and outputting excel data?

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007, vba

I am really new to excel macros and I was wondering if this was possible. I have 5 different types of excel sheets that get outputted every time. Let's call them starter, red, blue, green, and orange types. By "type" I mean the headers for each type are the same e.g. red has headers unique # | info1 | info2, blue has info 3 | info 4 | unique #, etc.

The thing these sheets have in common is that they all have the unique # header. I want to
1) taking the starter sheet pull the unique #s
2) compile all info with the same unique # in the other sheets
3) output an excel sheet with the unique # | info 1 | info2 | info3 | info4 etc.

Then I can analyze the data. I was wondering if this could be done solely with macros? or if there is a solution with access where I can submit a starter file into a form and it outputs an excel sheet of the data I want (for those unique #s).

Any hints for the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see that this has anything at all to do with Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done using a macro..

1. create a temp sheet (with all the necessary columns (unique #, info1, info2, formuls)
2. do a countif('range of the uniqueid', 'current row unique id')
3. filter select anything that is more than 1 (on the field with the formula).
4. copy the selection onto a different workbook.

voila.

if you aren't very well versed with VBA programming you can use the macro recorder to record the events & modify it to suit your needs.